# Dependent class is invalid and needs to be recompiled

Tags: apex, visualforce, deployment, visual-workflow, controller-extension

I have written a controller extension and am having difficulty deploying it to production. The extension allows a flow embedded in VF to finish on a Case record created during the flow.

The error I am getting is:"Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: UConnectFlowFinish: line 7, column 21: Expression of type Flow.Interview.UConnect_Intake has no member named varCaseID"

The flow has a variable varCaseID and it is set to "Input and Output." Also, I did not get this error while deploying to my test sandbox.

I have tried recompiling my code to no avail. Any thoughts as to how I can resolve this?

Comment: Does the flow exist in production? Does the flow have a controller that references the variable you mention? You may need to deploy the two separately as in the flow first, then the controller.

Comment: @crmprogdev That did it. Hadn't even thought that the flow changes were causing it. Thanks.